# I want to expose hidden menu when all process of mobile app has completed

Tags: android

I want to expose hidden menu when all process of mobile app has completed and this menu has to be exposed consistently, even the app is closed and rebooted.

I thought about the value remaining even the app is closed but I don't know how to do. let me know how to solve this problem.

```
public class Intro extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private final boolean notCleared = false;    
    private final boolean cleared = true;    
    private boolean status;

    private Button start;
    private Button what;
    private Button hidden;
    private Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        what = (Button) findViewById(R.id.whatButton);
        hidden = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hiddenButton);

        >>if(status) hidden.setVisibility(View.Visible);<<

        start.setOnClickListener(this);
        what.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: read this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) and come back here with more specific questions (including some code to show what you've tried so far)

Comment: Where is "this menu"? [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) may be one place to start looking.

Comment: @0X0nosugar I suppose that the app have the value **boolean notCleared = false, boolean cleared = true, boolean status = not Cleared**, I want setting **status = cleared** when I cleared all process of the app. and **status** value will not be changed even the app is closed. I'm not good in English so sorry for some weird sentences...

Comment: @KenY-N The thing what I want to know is the value not changed, even if the app is closed. sorry for bad English...

Comment: Your English is fine. but it's easier for people to help you if they have some relevant **piece of code** to work on - please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I thought the reason people gave me minus was problem of language. now I know what's wrong. thank you! and I added the codes. when the app is started, the app will check **status** and make a decision showing **hidden** or not.

Comment: I've removed my downvote now we have some code, but instead I have flagged this as a Duplicate; the linked answer has a complete solution that I hope will help you.

Comment: @KenY-N That's what I've lookig for. I didn't know about SharedPreferences. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem with SharedPreferences.
thanks for 0x0nosugar and Ken Y-N :-)

```
public class Intro extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private boolean isCleared;

    private Button start;
    private Button what;
    private Button hidden;
    private Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        what = (Button) findViewById(R.id.whatButton);
        hidden = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hiddenButton);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("isCleared", MODE_PRIVATE);

        //If someone complete all of processes,
        //SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("isCleared", MODE_PRIVATE);
        //SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        //editor.putBoolean("isCleared", true);
        //editor.commit();

        if(isCleared)
            hidden.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        start.setOnClickListener(this);
        what.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```